# Show that $\{\frac{e^n}{n!}\}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that the sequence $\{\frac{e^n}{n!}\}$ converges and that for prove it i have to limit it, but i don't know how do it.
In fact, i know that $\{\frac{x^n}{n!}\}$ converges, but i don't know prove it.
i want to aclarate that is convergence of the **sequence**, isn't of te serie.

Comment: Covering your bases a bit?

Comment: Whether intentional or not, you have posted the same question twice in a short space of time. Please refrain from this: all new questions appear on the front page, and your original question is still very much there.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n>3,$ then

$$\frac{e^n}{n!} = \frac{e}{n}\cdot\left(\frac{e}{n-1}\cdot\cdots \cdot \frac{e}{3}\right )\cdot\frac{e}{2}\cdot\frac{e}{1} < \frac{e^3}{2n} \to 0.$$